# Coloring a specific object in AndEngine

Tags: android, andengine

In my app I have a background and there is an object say a table placed on the background. Now I want to color the table only. Is there any way to do this in AndEngine? If so please provide a sample code.
What should be the mechanism?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set color to any entity on your scene.
Just use `entity.setColor()`. It will multiply your color and object native color.

If you need just new color, initially make your object white.

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in xml:

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/myTable"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" >
    <TableRow />
    <TableRow />
</TableLayout>
```

Or you can do it programmatically:

```
 TableLayout table = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.myTable);
 table.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);
```

Comment: I think I was unable to explain my question. I want to color the object in AndEngine Scene not in XML. Secondly I dont  want to change the background color I want to color the object. Like Kids do in their Drawing Books.